# Calculations from segments(looping) of a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

2 data frames. 1 short 1 long. I want to break the long one into chunks, to compare them to the short one, using correlation coefficient.

The splits are fine. However when putting them in calculation, it returns Nan.

```
import pandas as pd

data_a = {'ID': ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","a12","a13","a14","a15"], 
'Unit_Weight': [178,153,193,195,214,157,205,212,219,166,217,186,170,207,204]}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_a)

data_b = {'ID': ["b1","b2","b3","b4","b5"], 
'Unit_Weight': [128,123,123,125,204]}

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b)

size = 5      # 5 rows in the long data-frame
list_of_df_a = [df_a.loc[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df_a),size)]

for each in list_of_df_a:
    corr_e = each['Unit_Weight'].corr(df_b['Unit_Weight'])
```

Output:

```
0.6797202605786716
nan
nan
```

What went wrong, and how can it be corrected? Thank you.

p.s.: these are the results when manually calculated:

```
0.6797202605786716
-0.5501914564062937
0.2653370297540246

   ID  Unit_Weight
0  a1          178
1  a2          153
2  a3          193
3  a4          195
4  a5          214
    ID  Unit_Weight
5   a6          157
6   a7          205
7   a8          212
8   a9          219
9  a10          166
     ID  Unit_Weight
10  a11          217
11  a12          186
12  a13          170
13  a14          207
14  a15          204
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is necessary same indices in both `Series`, so use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
for each in list_of_df_a:
    corr_e = each['Unit_Weight'].reset_index(drop=True).corr(df_b['Unit_Weight'])
    print (corr_e)

0.6797202605786716
-0.5501914564062937
0.26533702975402457
```

Comment: good day to you, sir! thank you for the lightening speed and marvels question answering skills!

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael has a very good answer, but another way would be to change:

```
list_of_df_a = [df_a.loc[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df_a),size)]
```

To:

```
list_of_df_a = [df_a.loc[i:i+size-1,:].reset_index(drop=True) for i in range(0, len(df_a),size)]
```

And now your results would be:

```
0.6797202605786716
-0.5501914564062937
0.26533702975402457
```

Comment: thank you for sharing! certainly this helps a lot of people!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`numpy.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) to automatically take care of indexing problem:

```
for each in list_of_df_a:
    corr_e = np.corrcoef(each['Unit_Weight'], df_b['Unit_Weight'])[0,1]
    print(corr_e)

0.6797202605786716
-0.5501914564062937
0.2653370297540246
```